# Adding '% into SQL Command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, charts, sqlcommand

I have an SQL Query that i want to run throw my asp.net (WebForms) Project
The Query is:

```html
SELECT COUNT([order]) FROM menu_orders_Finished
WHERE [order] LIKE '%EXAMPLE%'
```

What i'm trying to do is

```html
con.Close();
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from menu",con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Series series = Chart2.Series["Series2"];
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                search = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([order]) FROM menu_orders_Finished WHERE [order] LIKE '%@order@%'", con);
                search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order", dr["name"].ToString());
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(search.ExecuteScalar());
                Label3.Visible = true;
                Label3.Text += count.ToString() + "+";
            }
            con.Close();
```

Which is Basically Counting how many times i'm having an order with one my menu items in the order (I want to make a chart of the best selling meal)

And then adding it in the chart (But i toke it off just to see what i get first)

Comment: the concat('%',@order,'%') should work. You can also use '%' + @order + '%' if you with. But there are 2 un-addressed issues. First name is likely reserved word, so use [name], and also what happens if name is null? You should wrap a if/then with a check for null and skip the row search. (or add [name] is not null to the main query that drives the loop. So I don't' think concat() is failing, but a null value would blow this up, and also  use [name] in place of name

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Develop good coding habits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want string concatenation:

```
search = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([order]) FROM menu_orders_Finished WHERE [order] LIKE CONCAT('%', @order, '%')", con);
```

Comment: This should work. What error message are you getting?